# Ordered list in Books navigation

Tags: theming, nodes

By default the navigation in books is an unordered list:

- Vegetables

  - Carrots
  - Tomatoes
- Fruits

  - Apples

Is there any way to make it an ordered list?

1. Vegetables

   1.1. Carrots

   1.2. Tomatoes
2. Fruits

   2.1. Apples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible manually.
Suppose you have a book entitled **"Tutorial"**. inside it you have created 3 book pages entitled : **"Installing"**, **"Configuring"**, **"Running"**.
When the book is dispalyed the 3 pages will be ordered starting with the most recent
[image]

To reorder the book, edit the book first and choose outline in the tabs
[image]

In that screen, click on the link **"reorder an entire book"**. The result wil be the following:
[image]
Click on the link **"edit order and titles"** to access the interface where you can reorder the pages
[image]
Use the + icons on the left of pages to reorder thje book.
I hope this will help.